# How to use QScxmlCppDataModel in QScxmlStateMachine?

Tags: c++, qt, scxml

In my project , i use C++ , QScxmlCppDataModel ,  there is always occur a error , "No data-model instantiated"  when i start the state machine,

I follow the Qt document says

1、Add data model in scxml file

```xml
<scxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml" version="1.0" binding="early" xmlns:qt="http://www.qt.io/2015/02/scxml-ext" datamodel="cplusplus:DataModel:DataModel.h" name="PowerStateMachine" qt:editorversion="4.6.1" initial="nomal">
```

2、Create a new data model subclass

```
#include "qscxmlcppdatamodel.h"
#include <QScxmlEvent>

class DataModel :public QScxmlCppDataModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_SCXML_DATAMODEL

public:
//    DataModel();

    bool isMoreThan50() const;
    bool isLessThan50() const ;

    int m_power;
    QString m_Descript;
    QVariant m_var;


};
```

3、load and start state machine

```
    m_stateMachine = QScxmlStateMachine::fromFile(":/powerStateMachine.scxml");
    for(QScxmlError& error:m_stateMachine->parseErrors())
    {
        qDebug()<<error.description();
    }
    m_stateMachine->connectToEvent("powerLoss", this, &MainWindow::onPowerLossEvent);
    m_stateMachine->connectToEvent("pwoerUp", this, &MainWindow::onPowerUpEvent);

    m_stateMachine->connectToState("low", this, &MainWindow::onLowState);
    m_stateMachine->connectToState("nomal", this, &MainWindow::onNomalState);
    m_stateMachine->connectToState("danger", this, &MainWindow::onDangerState);
    m_stateMachine->connectToState("full", this, &MainWindow::onFullState);
    DataModel *dataModel = new DataModel;
    m_stateMachine->setDataModel(dataModel);
    m_stateMachine->init();

    m_stateMachine->start();
```

error image

[image]

but still have a error :"No data-model instantiated",when i start the 
state machine , anybody know how to fix it ?? thank you

Comment: share your .pro, provide a [MRE]

Comment: here is my example  https://github.com/ZhongYoulin/zhongyl  ,thanks

Comment: compare your xml file against a working example like the Qt SCXML Calculator Example.

Comment: Actually ， I 'm follow that example to do , i had check times ,

Answer (score 1):

Qt's documentation on `QScxmlCppDataModel` specifically says:

> The C++ data model for SCXML ... cannot be used when loading an SCXML
> file at runtime.

And that is exactly what you are doing, so instead of loading the scxml file at runtime:

```
m_stateMachine = QScxmlStateMachine::fromFile(":/powerStateMachine.scxml");
```

Use the compiled statemachine directly:

```
MyStateMachine statemachine;
MyDataModel datamodel;
statemachine.setDataModel(&datamodel);
```

In the example above:

1-  `MyStateMachine` is the value you have assigned to the `<name>` attribute of the scxml element (i.e. scxml file/model).

2- `MyDataModel` is the name you have given to your c++ data model class (i.e. your class derived from `QScxmlCppDataModel`)

```
class MyDataModel : public QScxmlCppDataModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_SCXML_DATAMODEL
public:
    MyDataModel();
};
```

Too late an answer, but hope it helps others.